# How do I build a Vue app to use it in another app?

Tags: vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue and to dev in general. I was asked to dev an app in Vue.
So I did it, with multiple components, to make the code as maintainable as possible. I also installed dependencies
But now, this app must be usable in another Vue app... And I can't find how to build it so I can import it in another app. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use build targets like `library` or `web-component` for this.
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app

Comment: Having vue globally is necessary?